# Moments of a continuous random variable (Exercise 4.3.3 from Grimmett and Stirzaker)

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, proof-writing

Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable with density function $f$. Show that
$$
E(X^r) = \int_0^\infty r x^{r-1} P(X > r)\,dx.
$$

I tried using integration by parts to obtain
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty r x^{r-1} P(X > r)\,dx &= \int_0^\infty r x^{r-1} (1 - F(x))\,dx, \\
&= [x^r]_0^{\infty} + \int_0^\infty x^r f(x)\,dx.
\end{align}

Where is the mistake in the above calculation and how do I get rid of the first term on the right to obtain the required result? Any hints would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first term should be $[x^r(1-F(x)]_0^{\infty}=0-0$.

Comment: Doh! I should be more careful.

Comment: You need to show that $\lim_{x\to\infty}( x^r(1-F(x))=0$, which does require some care.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution

$$
\begin{align}
E(X^r) & = \int_0^{\infty} r x^{r-1} P(X > x) \:dx \\
&= \int_0^{\infty} r x^{r-1} \left[ \int_{y=x}^{\infty} f(y) \:dy \right] \:dx \\
&= \int_{y=0}^{\infty} f(y) \left[ \int_{x=0}^{y}r x^{r-1} \,dx \right]\:dy  \\
&= \int_0^{\infty} y^r f(y)\,dy
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you for the alternative method.